# Google web font

Tags: fonts, google-webfonts

In a new project, we decide to use Gooogle Web Font. It pretty easy to set it up. But I see the font is rendering differently from monitor to monitor and even browser to browser.

How that could be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two good articles about the topic, written by the TypeKit team:

http://blog.typekit.com/2010/10/05/type-rendering-on-the-web
http://blog.typekit.com/2010/10/15/type-rendering-operating-systems

The visual result of a rendered font is influenced by many things. Notably pixel density on displays and the way subpixels are rendered. Unfortunately subpixel rendering is different from operating system to operating system and from browser to browser.

Subpixel-Rendering: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering

The nearest you get to a consistent appearance is with well-hinted and optimized fonts.
But Google doesn't seem to have a way to find only optimized fonts. So your back to testing :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem from Google Web font.

In fact, there is never a standard for how to render a font, so even a truetype font, theres always difference browser by browser, system by system, cleartyped or not ....

Theres nothing more you can do, we have to just live with it.

Comment: Thank you! But apparently, some web safe font, like Arial, is much more compatible than Google Font. As Jonas said,"The nearest you get to a consistent appearance is with well-hinted and optimized fonts. But Google doesn't seem to have a way to find only optimized fonts."

Comment: IMHO, forget about fancy fonts (for whole page), I always use "font-family: Geneva,sans-serif;", simple and easy. Fancy fonts just for decor, not for whole page